# PHP Regular Expression {{ }}

Tags: php, regex

I am having some tough time writing a PHP regular expression for preg_match. Basically I need to match following pattern:

```
{{anything}}
{{{anything}}}
```

But this is the easy part. I want to replace such expressions with "" (empty string) if the string only contains this but if string contains something else, i need to keep, so following strings will become valid:

```
this is about {{anything}}
{{{anything}}} anywhere
```

Help is much appreciated :).

Comment: looks like the linebreaks didn't work. please note there is line breaks around {{   }}

Comment: First check if the string contains whatever 'this' is were looking for when you said "if the string only contains this" then if that is the case use preg_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use anchors.

```
preg_replace('~^\{+[^{}]*\}+$\n?~m', '', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yL0yM6/1)

Comment: Needs to end with `\}+`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [T-Regx](https://t-regx.com)

```
pattern('\{+[^{}]*\}+')->replace()->all()->callback(function (Match $m) {
    if ($m->text() === 'anything') {
        return '';
    }
    return $m->text();
});
```